# Second WordPress loop failing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two loops running on my page one for getting one set of posts from a specific category and then further down getting posts from a custom post type but for some reason If I output both of them the second loop does not show and if I comment out the first the second one does show?

Im a bit confused as to why?

**FIRST LOOP UPDATED**

```
<?php

  $post_query = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => 'email-content'));

  if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<div class="tabs tabs_default">';
    echo '<ul class="horizontal">';
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
      $post_query->the_post();
      $title = strtolower(get_the_title());
      $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
      echo'<li><a href="#'.$title.'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    } 

    echo '</ul>';

    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
      $post_query->the_post();
      $title = strtolower(get_the_title());
      $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
      echo '<div id="'.$title.'">';
      echo '<div><button class="copy" id="'.$title.'" data-clipboard-text="'.get_the_content().'" title="Copy">Copy</button></div>';
      echo '<div>'.get_the_content().'</div>';
      echo '</div>';
    } 

    $post_query->reset_postdata();

  }
?>
```

**SECOND LOOP UPDATED**

I didn't need one of the loops so I refined the code a bit further but still I am not having any luck with the second loop outputting.

```
<?php

$featureThumb = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'resources',
    'meta_key'          => 'file_upload',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1
));

while ($featureThumb->have_posts()) : $featureThumb->the_post();

echo '<div>';

    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {

        $thumb  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'homepage-thumb-thumb' );
        echo '<img src="' . $thumb[0] . '" width="200" height="200" />' ;

    }; 

echo '<p><a href="'. get_field('file_upload') .'" target="_blank" download>Click here to download as PDF</a></p>';

endwhile;

unset($featureThumb); 

}

?>
```

Comment: Your second query is `$featureThumb` but you're then looping over `$loop`. Also, call `wp_reset_postdata()` after each loop; this resets the global `$post` variable.

Comment: @Dre so is my code just a little jumbled up? I have got myself into a little bit of confusion with it here. So I do `wp_reset_postdata` after the first post loop right? Anf then I change `$loop` to `$featureThumb` ?

Comment: @Dre I have updated my question to reflect our discussion - am I doing it right as still the second loop fails to output

Comment: I have narrowed it down to something being wrong with the first post loop because when I switch them around they all show but I am not sure what is so different about them?

Comment: Should you not remove the first "wp_reset_postdata();" You only need to run this function once you dont need the $post_query object anymore. You're running the second while loop but the query has already been reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have three queries and 4 loops, not two.

Also, you have an extra `}` after the `unset($featureThumb);` that you should remove.

The three queries you posted in your question are:

`$post_query`, `$loop` and `$featureThumb`. At the last one your loop is incorect. It uses the object of the second one. Change at the third query in the loop, `$loop` with  `$featureThumb`.

You need to use `wp_reset_postdata()` after the first two queries instead of `wp_reset_query()` as someone suggested and it should both work.

`wp_reset_query()` ensures that the main query has been reset to the original main query, while on the other hand `wp_reset_postdata()` makes sure that the global `$post` has been restored to the current post in the main query.

**UPDATE**:

If that does not work, if global `$post` object is not defined, try:

`$post_query->reset_postdata();`

`$loop->reset_postdata();`

**UPDATE 2**:

Your first query and loop should look like this:

```html
<?php

  $post_query = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => 'email-content'));

  if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<div class="tabs tabs_default">';
    echo '<ul class="horizontal">';
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
      $post_query->the_post();
      $title = strtolower(get_the_title());
      $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
      echo'<li><a href="#'.$title.'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    } 

    echo '</ul>';

    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
      $post_query->the_post();
      $title = strtolower(get_the_title());
      $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
      echo '<div id="'.$title.'">';
      echo '<div><button class="copy" id="'.$title.'" data-clipboard-text="'.get_the_content().'" title="Copy">Copy</button></div>';
      echo '<div>'.get_the_content().'</div>';
      echo '</div>';
    } 

    $post_query->reset_postdata();

  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time to explain both resets as I was not aware of this. So do I need to reset after each loop?

Comment: After each loop, but not after the last one, as there's no need to put it there.

Comment: So I have placed a reset after each while loop but still the first loop shows but the second one is still not showing?

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect our discussion - am I doing it right as still the second loop fails to output

Comment: The `wp_reset_postdata` is called by `wp_reset_query` function, so it's the same and better because the second one resets also the query. You can see the code [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/query.php#L109)

Comment: The strange thing is there must be an issue surrounding the first post query because if I move that code block to underneath the the second and third code blocks they all output so it must be something to do with the reset?

Comment: @danjbh, see my updated answer, try the last two lines. Replace `wp_reset_postdata()` with those.

Comment: @Ionut so now I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function reset_postdata() on a non-objec`

Comment: @danjbh, do it only once in the first query, after the second while. I've also seen that you updated your code, please don't do that anymore as it makes us more confuse, as you started with one code, and now you have another.

Comment: @danjbh, what `kills everything off ` means? Are there any errors?

Comment: Also, I've seen that you also removed the `$loop` query from your question. If you don't have that in your code anymore please don't use `$loop->reset_postdata()` on that.

Comment: I have updated my question and reduced the loops down to two as before it was essentially doing the same thing twice, so I took your suggestion and tried to reset both the loops, then the first one and then the second one but all just shows the first loop still and not the second one... I really can;t understand why when I remove the first loop the second loop show just fine?

Comment: I changed your suggestion to `$featureThumb->reset_postdata()`

Comment: @danjbh, now you don't actually check if there are any post on the second query. You can do it like `if($featureThumb->have_posts()){ //your code here }`. Maybe you don't have any posts, or maybe `meta_key` is no correct. If you remove the first query the second one works?

Comment: hi, I do have posts because it is 100% in the backend and also if i remove the first loop it appears... Regarding your last suggestion could you show me what you mean because I added it and it still outputs nothing?

Comment: @danjbh, do you have this website live? Can you give me a link to the page?

Comment: I do yes on a development domain - here http://jbhconcept.co.uk/dev/ncsleaderboard/marketing-materials/

Comment: Thank you, I re wrote it with your suggestions and now seem to be working.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it worked. It coul've been also a caching issue, and maybe took a little time to work or needed a refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `wp_reset_query();` at the end of the first loop as well. So the first loop should be:

```
<?php

  $post_query = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => 'email-content'));

  if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="tabs tabs_default">';
    echo '<ul class="horizontal">';
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
      $post_query->the_post();
      $title = strtolower(get_the_title());
      $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
      echo'<li><a href="#'.$title.'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
      $post_query->the_post();
      $title = strtolower(get_the_title());
      $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
      echo '<div id="'.$title.'">';
      echo '<div><button class="copy" id="'.$title.'" data-clipboard-text="'.get_the_content().'" title="Copy">Copy</button></div>';
      echo '<div>'.get_the_content().'</div>';
      echo '</div>';
    }

    wp_reset_query();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I thought that would be the case but it just isn't resettings, I have tried your code just incase I perhaps missed something but still the second loop fails.

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust also the third loop, because you do `$featureThumb = new WP_Query(...)` and after that you do `while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();`. You saved the instance in `$featureThumb` and not `$loop`. I suggest you anyway to leave `wp_reset_query()` function.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused, what would you suggest I amend, so change thew name of the `$loop` variable name?

Comment: Yes, in the third loop you should use `while ($featureThumb->have_posts()) : $featureThumb->the_post();`.

Comment: So I have updated that and If I comment out the first loop it still shows howver if I bring back on the first loop is fails again

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect our discussion - am I doing it right as still the second loop fails to output